How to handle field dependency between picklist fields in pre-chat API aura component in Salesforce?
As you know The pre-chat API does not automatically handle field dependency between picklist fields. You need to implement the logic to retrieve and set the dependent picklist values based on the selected value of the controlling picklist manually in your code.
Below is the Entire Aura component, We have field dependency among Support_Product__c and Support_Product_Topic__c in the salesforce but it's not working in the Prechat form.
Aura Component
<aura:component implements="lightningsnapin:prechatUI" description="Sample custom pre-chat component for Embedded Chat. Implemented using Aura.">
    <!-- You must implement "lightningsnapin:prechatUI" for this component to appear in the "Pre-chat Component" customization dropdown in the Embedded Service setup -->
 
    <!-- Pre-chat field components to render -->
    <aura:attribute name="prechatFieldComponents" type="List" description="An array of objects representing the pre-chat fields specified in pre-chat setup."/>
    
    <!-- Handler for when this component is initialized -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}" />
 
    <!-- For Aura performance -->
    <aura:locator target="startButton" description="Pre-chat form submit button."/>
    
    <!-- Contains methods for getting pre-chat fields, starting a chat, and validating fields -->
    <lightningsnapin:prechatAPI aura:id="prechatAPI"/>
    
    <h2 style="margin-top:8px !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;">How can we help?</h2>
   
   <div class="stateBody embeddedServiceSidebarState">
        <div class="prechatUI embeddedServiceLiveAgentStatePrechatDefaultUI">
            <div class="formContent embeddedServiceSidebarForm">
                <ul class="slds-p-around_medium">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.prechatFieldComponents}" var="eachField">
                        <li class="inputText embeddedServiceSidebarFormField slds-p-around_medium slds-text-align_left">
                            {!eachField}                    
                        </li>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </ul>
            </div>
                
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-p-around_small">
                <div class="startButtonWrapper buttonWrapper embeddedServiceSidebarForm">
                    <ui:button aura:id="startButton" class="startChatButton uiButton--default uiButton embeddedServiceSidebarButton" label="{!$Label.LiveAgentPrechat.StartChat}" press="{!c.handleStartButtonClick}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>


JS
({
   
    onInit: function(cmp, evt, hlp) {
        // Get pre-chat fields defined in setup using the prechatAPI component
        var prechatFields = cmp.find("prechatAPI").getPrechatFields();
        // Get pre-chat field types and attributes to be rendered
        var prechatFieldComponentsArray = hlp.getPrechatFieldAttributesArray(prechatFields);
        
        // Make asynchronous Aura call to create pre-chat field components
        $A.createComponents(
            prechatFieldComponentsArray,
            function(components, status, errorMessage) {
                if(status === "SUCCESS") {
                    cmp.set("v.prechatFieldComponents", components);
                }
            }
        );
    },
    
  
    handleStartButtonClick: function(cmp, evt, hlp) {
        hlp.onStartButtonClick(cmp);
    }
});


JS helper
({
    
    fieldLabelToName: {
        "First Name": "FirstName",
        "Last Name": "LastName",
        "Email": "Email",
        "Phone": "Phone",
        "Fax": "Fax",
        "Mobile": "MobilePhone",
        "Home Phone": "HomePhone",
        "Other Phone": "OtherPhone",
        "Asst. Phone": "AssistantPhone",
        "Title": "Title",
        "Lead Source": "LeadSource",
        "Assistant": "AssistantName",
        "Department": "Department",
        "Subject": "Subject",
        "Case Reason": "Reason",
        "Type": "Type",
        "Web Company": "SuppliedCompany",
        "Web Phone": "SuppliedPhone",
        "Priority": "Priority",
        "Web Name": "SuppliedName",
        "Web Email": "SuppliedEmail",
        "Company": "Company",
        "Industry": "Industry",
        "Rating": "Rating",
        "Client ID Entered":"Client_ID_Entered__c",
        "Support Product":"Support_Product__c",
        "Support Product Topic" : "Support_Product_Topic__c"
    },
    
   onStartButtonClick: function(cmp) {
        var prechatFieldComponents = cmp.find("prechatField");
        var fields;

        // Make an array of field objects for the library
        fields = this.createFieldsArray(prechatFieldComponents);
        
        // If the pre-chat fields pass validation, start a chat
        if(cmp.find("prechatAPI").validateFields(fields).valid) {
            cmp.find("prechatAPI").startChat(fields);
        } else {
            console.warn("Prechat fields did not pass validation!");
        }
    },

    
    createFieldsArray: function(fields) {
        if(fields.length) {
            return fields.map(function(fieldCmp) {
                return {
                    label: fieldCmp.get("v.label"),
                    value: fieldCmp.get("v.value"),
                    name: this.fieldLabelToName[fieldCmp.get("v.label")]
                };
            }.bind(this));
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    },
    
   
    getPrechatFieldAttributesArray: function(prechatFields) {
        // $A.createComponents first parameter is an array of arrays. Each array contains the type of component being created, and an Object defining the attributes.
        var prechatFieldsInfoArray = [];

        // For each field, prepare the type and attributes to pass to $A.createComponents
        prechatFields.forEach(function(field) {
            var componentName = (field.type === "inputSplitName") ? "inputText" : field.type;
            var componentInfoArray = ["ui:" + componentName];
            var attributes = {
                "aura:id": "prechatField",
                required: field.required,
                label: field.label,
                disabled: false,
                maxlength: field.maxLength,
                class: field.className,
                value: field.value
            };
            
            // Special handling for options for an input:select (picklist) component
            if(field.type === "inputSelect" && field.picklistOptions) attributes.options = field.picklistOptions;
            if(field.label === "First Name" )   attributes.disabled = true; attributes.class = 'hideClass'; 
            if(field.label === "Last Name" ) attributes.disabled = true;
            if(field.label === "Email" ) attributes.disabled = true;
            // Append the attributes Object containing the required attributes to render this pre-chat field
            componentInfoArray.push(attributes);
            
            // Append this componentInfoArray to the fieldAttributesArray
            prechatFieldsInfoArray.push(componentInfoArray);
        });

        return prechatFieldsInfoArray;
    }
});

